# How come git status detects changes, after performing git reset --mixed <commit id>?

Tags: git

I'm breaking my head in an attempt to understand how git reset works. I've read various articles, played with my demo repo - and i still don't get exactly what's going on there. When i do git reset --hard, the result is intuitive for me("everything" just goes back to the way it was in that specified commit), but when i do the default git reset --mixed, that's where my confusion begins.

[resetting-checking-out-and-reverting](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting)  This is what this article says about git reset --mixed:

> The staged snapshot is updated to match the specified commit, but the working directory is not affected. This is the default option.

My understanding is, that this would mean that git status will detect **no changes**, being that the staged snapshot is now "updated to match the specified commit...".

To my surprise, git status actually shows unstaged changes, corresponding to the **last commit**, before the git reset --mixed.

I assume i'm getting something totally wrong here, and would appreciate it if someone will explain me this issue in simple words, because reading all those articles and posts didn't do the trick :D

Answer (score 2):

`git reset --mixed` without a commit id simply unstages everything you had staged (if you had anything). `git reset --mixed <commit id>` removes all commits up until the specified commit but leaves all those changes in the working directory. As the result they are seen as unstaged (and even possibly untracked) changes.

Comment: OK, i think i understand, more or less :D

Answer (score 1):

[image: Diagram of working directory, directory, staging area and git repository]

Let's say you have a repo with two commits commitA, followed by commitB, you are currently on commitA.

If you do:

```
git reset --hard commitA
```

You will go back to your state at commitA, this means you will lose the changes you made.

However, if you do

```
git reset commitA # same as --mixed
```

Your working directory will not be cleaned, the changes will not be lost, they will be only unstaged and uncommited.

The last option:

```
git reset --soft commitA
```

will "uncommit your changes", meaning they will be in your staging area.

---

Some reproduction for clarity, `git log` shows:

```
commit 03c71ae050d1fff5d6eede18d6a3a8861076ba6a

Added bar

commit 39e0af4635f550b56cb6f887de43d28874d55b72

Added foo
```

I have two files in my directory, `foo` and `bar`

```
git reset --hard 03c71ae050d1fff5d6eede18d6a3a8861076ba6a
```

will bring me back to the first commit and completely remove the `bar` file.

```
git reset 03c71ae050d1fff5d6eede18d6a3a8861076ba6a
```

will mark `bar` as untracked

```
git reset --soft 03c71ae050d1fff5d6eede18d6a3a8861076ba6a
```

will mark `bar` in changes to be committed.